# Cambiar el valor de una variable luego de recibirla a través de una función callback

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto, javascript-import

Quisiera ayuda por favor en cómo hacer lo siguiente: Estoy modificando un programa no escrito por mí. En el programa hay una variable que se define al principio del programa a través de una asignación normal. Yo quiero que este valor cambie dinámicamente a través de lo que reciba por ejemplo desde una hoja de cálculo de google.
Para ello utilizo una libreria que consulta la google sheet, y devuelve los datos a través de un archivo JSON en una función callback. Puedo acceder al archivo y extraer el valor que requiero, pero mi problema es que no puedo reasignar el valor ya que la función callback lo devuelve luego de un tiempo. Es decir:

```
var a = 0;
.
.
function callback(x, y){  // los parámetros x, y son necesarios para acceder a la información

// Recibo los datos en JSON y extraigo el valor requerido "b = 100"

a = b;
console.log (a) // 100
}

console.log(a);   // 0
```

He intentado varias cosas pero no logro llegar a que la variable a=100 luego de la función y poder utiliar más adelante en el código.
Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras, inmediatamente después de asignar el valor `0`, ejecuta la línea `console.log(a)`, por lo que es normal que imprima `0`, ya que la función `callback()` no ha sido invocada y no se ha ejecutado.

Si tu quieres que dicho código se ejecute después del callback, puedes meterlo en una función e invocarlo al final del callback, por ejemplo:

```
var a = 0;
.
.
function callback(x, y){  // los parámetros x, y son necesarios para acceder a la información

  // Recibo los datos en JSON y extraigo el valor requerido "b = 100"

  a = b;
  console.log (a); // 100
  despues();
}

function despues() {
  console.log(a);  //ahora imprimirá 100
}
```

Como ves, ahora es el callback el que *lanza* la ejecución del código después de haber realizado la asignación, por lo que debiera imprimir el valor correcto.

Otra posible alternativa que te recomiendo investigar es el uso de [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), que pueden combinarse con las palabras reservadas `async/await` y podrían lograr que el código siga luciendo de manera similar al código original que tienes.

Para poder utilizarlas, sin embargo, habría que ver las capacidades que tiene la biblioteca a quién le estás entregando actualmente el `callback()`, pues esta tendría que tener soporte para entregarte una promesa.

Si lo hace, tu código podría parecer algo como:

```
var a = 0;
miJSON = await llamadaAsincrona();
// Recibo los datos en JSON y extraigo el valor requerido "b = 100"
a = b;
console.log(a);   // 100
```

En este caso, la asignación `a=b` ocurre hasta que la llamada asíncrona ha finalizado.

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder al valor modificado dentro de una llamada asíncrona, **desde afuera de dicha función**, de alguna manera hay que esperar que esa función se ejecute.  Una forma es usando el `await`, el cual tiene que estar dentro de un `async`.

En el ejemplo de abajo simulamos una llamada asíncrona con `setTimeout`

```js
var a = 0;

function callback() {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { //<-- devuelve una promesa

    setTimeout(() => {

      a = 100;

      resolve(true)

    }, 3000);

  });

}

(async () => { //<--  await tiene que estar dentro de async

  await callback();// <-- espera los 3 segundos aqui
  console.log(a); // <-- 100


})();
```